# Native Base two headers

Tags: reactjs, react-native, native-base

I have created the header with title and right icon by using native base. However, there are two headers showing on my simulator. I have no idea what is going on. Can someone help me with this?

```
import React, { Component }from 'react';
import { StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { Icon, Button, Container, Header, Content, Left, Right, Body,Text, Title } from 'native-base';

class Landing extends Component {
 render() {
    return (
        <Container>
            <Header>
                <Left />
                <Body>
                    <Title>
                        Title
                    </Title>
                </Body>
                <Right>
                    <Button transparent>
                    <Icon name="ios-menu" onPress={() => 
                    this.props.navigation.navigate('DrawerOpen')} />
                    </ Button>
                </Right>
            </Header>
            <Content contentContainerStyle={{
                flex: 1,
                alignItems: 'center',
                justifyContent: 'center'
            }}>
            <Text> 
                Landing Screen
            </Text>
            </ Content>
        </ Container>
    );
}
}


export default Landing;
```

This is my code and I am seeing something like the picture:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gWcyu.png)

Answer (score 4):

I think you are using `StackNavigator`.

if yes then change to:

```
const Navigator = StackNavigator(
    {
        Landing: { screen: Landing},
        Home: { screen: Home}
    },
    {
        headerMode: 'none'
    }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are `react-navigation` then you have to set navigation Options as follows:

```
  static navigationOptions = {
    header: null
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

In [react-router-flux](https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux) is the same idea of the accepted answer at routes/navigators:

```js
<Scene
      key='dashboardContainer'
      component={(localProps) => <DashboardContainer {...props} {...localProps} />}
      hideNavBar
/>
```